# Can we call the coefficient of an algebraic expression a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, education

Can we call the coefficient of an algebraic expression a constant?

For example, in $6y$ is the $6$ a constant?

Comment: No. Coefficients are multipliers, but constants are fixed values. If it were plain $6$, then that would be a constant because the expression is unchanging. In $6y$, the 6 becomes a coefficient, a multiplier of a variable.

Comment: can we say that 1 is a constant in the above algebraic expression.
Forexample in 6y can we say 1 is a constant or there is no constant?

Comment: "constant", "parameter", "variable" all mean the same, only with different levels or scopes of variability. Yes, $6$ is a constant, whether it appers in an expression such as $6x$ or elsewhere, for it is certainly not variable. However, $6$ is not *the constant term* in the polynomial $6x$

Answer (score 1):

The number $6$  is fixed and , in the expression $6y$ it is constant, in the sense that we can chose any value for $y$ , but the expression indicate that this value is always multiplied by the constant number $6$. Obviously the expression $6y$ is not a constant if we can chose different values of $y$.

Comment: The Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics clarifies: “coefficient 1. In general, the product of all the factors in an expression except for a specified factor. Thus the coefficients of x in the expressions 3x, (a + b) x, and 2xyz are respectively 3, (a + b), and 2yz. A coefficient is usually a constant.” That is, it’s a constant because it does not vary, but it’s not the constant term of an algebraic expression.

Answer (score 0):

For the polynomial  $$ P(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_nx^n $$the constants,$$ a_0, a_1,a_2,...,a_n$$ are called coefficients.

They are constants but using the word constant may apply  only to $a_0$

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Clark's Dictionary of Analysis, Calculus, and Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books?id=jQL4ZU4RjPYC&pg=PA45&dq=A+quantity+that+does+not+vary.+A+symbol+that+represents+the+same+quantity+throughout+a+discussion.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR6eDYvYPbAhVCHJAKHVq0AF0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=A%20quantity%20that%20does%20not%20vary.%20A%20symbol%20that%20represents%20the%20same%20quantity%20throughout%20a%20discussion.&f=false), a *constant* is

> A quantity that does not vary. A symbol that represents the same quantity
>   throughout a discussion.

And, according to the [Krantz's Dictionary of Algebra, Arithmetic, and Trigonometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=RvUoI39g2cAC&dq=Krantz%27s%20dictionary%20math&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_book_other_versions),

> Given an equation in a variable $x$, any part of the equation that is independent of $x$ is a constant term.

So, in these senses: yes, we can say that the coefficients of algebraic expressions are constants.

But note that some constants are not coefficients and "variable coefficients" appear in some contexts.

Comment: hi @Pedro, would you happen to know an alternative good reference dictionary book for analysis, calculus and differential equations ?

Comment: @8c6b5df0d16ade6c Not sure what you need, but the following can be useful: Dictionary of Applied Math for Engineers and Scientists, McGraw-Hill dictionary of mathematics, Collins Dictionary of Mathematics, Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics.